# How to commit on a Google Code branch

Tags: php, svn, google-code

How do I commit to a Google Code Subversion branch by using the [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) thingy?

Apparently I am having a problem with it because TortoiseSVN is asking for a username and password. I input the email address that I used to create the project and the corresponding password for it and it didn't work.

#### Update:

Great, I was able to commit. But I have a new question now, is it possible to delete the test folders that I committed in Google Code?

Comment: Google Code [was shut](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) [down on 2016-01-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Developers#Google_Code). But there is no close option for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

You generate a separate password for the SVN login.

Go to your settings in Google Code, and set a Google Code Password. This is separate from your google.com login.

Check out [**this tutorial**](http://devwatch.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/how-to-access-google-code-svn/) for a step-by-step walkthrough.

Comment: the tutorial as was cool, but am having this error http://i46.tinypic.com/2rel7hi.jpg

Comment: Did you give your user name *without* @gmail.com?

Comment: It does work without @gmail.com but the password is not the same as the one for gmail (for security purpose).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use `https://` instead of `http://` to commit code to [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code).